# Does .NET 4 Parallel Extensions include an implementation of a lock-free Producer/Consumer queue?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, parallel-processing, producer-consumer

Does .NET 4 Parallel Extensions include an implementation of a lock-free Producer/Consumer queue? Is there any class or interface to implement which could help me to implement this pattern correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe .NET 4.0 will ship with this, but you can follow Joe Duffy's blog post ["Fast synchronization between a single producer and single consumer"](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2009/10/05/FastSynchronizationBetweenASingleProducerAndSingleConsumer.aspx) to build one yourself.

Answer (score 1):

BlockingCollection can be used to implement that pattern.